# How can you put dict and get method inside an f-string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, f-string

I have this dictionary that I want to embed inside an f-string to shorten up my code (for golfing purposes). Is there any way to include the braces inside the f-string braces?

```
# what I have:
i=2
a={1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}.get(i,'g')
b=f'{a} is the letter'

# what I want to do but get a syntax error:
b=f'{{1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}.get(i,'g')} is the letter'

# desired output:
'b is the letter'
```

I can't swap out the `{}.get` notation for the `dict().get` because my keys are numbers (unless there's a hack to adjust that but it probably will end up being more characters than I have already).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want the output to look like?

Comment: I just added some clarity on that @Greg

Comment: ```f"{dict([(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]).get(i, 'g')} is the letter"```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One, you have to use different quote types on your string, otherwise the quotes inside the dict literal will mess things up. Secondly, you just have to add a space around the dictionary literal and the `.get()`:

```
b=f"{ {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}.get(i,'g') } is the letter"
```

Source for adding the spaces: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53937779/6273251).

Comment: _Why_ do you have to add the extra spaces?

Comment: @martineau great question, if I could explain it I would have.

Comment: Actually I think the question the answer you added the link to explains it: "…double brackets result in literal brackets in the output…", i.e. it's just how f-strings are parsed.